# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cache'

Tags: python, python-2.7, client, suds

```
import suds

s = suds.client.Client('http://hello-world.org/ttsoapcgi.wsdl',
                       cache=suds.cache.NoCache())
```

I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cache' for above line.
```

I have installed suds 0.3.7 version

What's the reason for this and how to solve this ?

Comment: What version of suds are ou using? I tested your code with suds 0.4, and ``suds.cache.NoCache()`` does not raise any exception.

Comment: @BalthazarRouberol i have downloaded python-suds-0.3.7.tar.gz

Comment: I confirm that the API you're using is not present in the 0.3.7 version. I suggest you download the latest version (eg: with ``pip``).

Comment: @BalthazarRouberol pip command for installing suds 0.4 ?

Comment: I guess the command must be in the documentation, but here it is. ``pip install suds==0.4``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update suds version to 0.4

The API used is not present in suds 0.3.7 version